# Why isn't onEach function defined for Kotlin Arrays?

Tags: collections, kotlin, api-design

The `Collection` API contains the `onEach` function (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/on-each.html) which behaves like a non terminal sibling of `forEach`.

Why isn't `onEach` defined for `Array`s?

**Edit**: I guess the system works and the feature is available since 1.4. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28290

Answer (score 1):

The "Why" is probably not something to be answered here, it could be for many reasons including an oversight, something that just hasn't yet been done, some really good reason that it is a bad idea, or other.  You can file a bug/request in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT (or see if there is an existing one).

In the meantime, you can easily have your own:

```
inline fun <T> Array<T>.onEach(action: (T) -> Unit): Array<T> {
    return apply { for (element in this) action(element) }
}

inline fun IntArray.onEach(action: (Int) -> Unit): IntArray {
    return apply { for (element in this) action(element) }
}

// and a version for each primitive array type would need to be created...
```

Comment: Thank you Jayson. I can see how the implementation of onEach in Collection translates to Array. My question is really about the API design. It came from me puzzling over the differences between the two APIs. Chunked and windowed are also missing from Array while fill is not in Collection

Comment: David, "why" questions are not really great Stack Overflow questions if you want to talk to the language designers, go to the Kotlin forums, or the language design in the Kotlin slack.  There are a lot of people working on Kotlin and you likely will get wrong answers here and assumptions (from people not even involved).  But likely the answer is "we haven't gotten to it yet" given that Kotlin is always a work in progress...

Comment: Lastly, if you did go and ask for it on the Kotlin issue tracker, you would either see it happen, or receive a reason why it would not happen.

Comment: Makes sense, will do.